# How to send http request in SSMS with Basic Authentication passing Username and Password?

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, t-sql, http

So I'm using an API today that returns XML file upon http request. Today I don't have any authentication in this process, but API website will put more security in place. So instead of 'No Auth' I would need to be passing Username and Password.

Here's the code I'm using today

```
DECLARE @authHeader VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @contentType VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @responseText varchar(4000);
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url varchar(8000);
--DECLARE @username varchar(255);  will use in the future
--DECLARE @password varchar(255);  will use in the future


SET @authHeader  = 'No Auth'
SET @contentType = 'application/xml';
SET @url = 'https://www.someurl.com/get_xml';

-- Open the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
```

How do I pass same http `get` request but with Basic Authentication, passing `Username: Login` and `Password: Admin`?
I've tried to research online but couldn't find much information in that regard

Comment: Don't pass a password. You should be salting and hashing passwords. Passing and storing plain text passwords are a huge security risk.

Comment: My IP address would be whitelisted and password would be hashed, so it's not a plain custom 'qwerty' password

Comment: Can you use SQL CLR instead of the deprecated sp_OA.... extended stored procedures?  You'll find lots of samples of how to to HTTP Basic Authentication in C#.

Comment: I'm doing research in that regard, I found few C# scripts that I test now, but CLR method takes 20-30 sec per each request which is very slow for my needs. So I'm trying to stick with sp_OA.. but if there are no choice i'll use CLR

Comment: This should answer your immediate question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/755/how-does-basic-http-auth-work

Comment: As others said it is not the best idea to call webservices/APIs from SQL Server. If your DB logic depends on a remote API call returning quickly, then it is a major problem in the design. What happens if internet connection goes down? What if it becomes very slow? I would implement this functionality in a .NET application that would run as a windows service. You can still achieve reasonably quick turnaround (~15-30 sec), and it would also be considerably more robust.

Comment: Why are you doing this from within the database in the first place? Why expend SQL Server resources (very expensive) when a script on another, much cheaper, system can do this in a less convoluted way?